# Database error in cpanel while uploading codeigniter project

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

While uploading a CodeIgniter project in cPanel, an error occurred:

> A Database Error Occurred
>
> Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.
>
> Filename: core/Loader.php
>
> Line Number: 346

```
$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'db user';
$db['default']['password'] = 'password';
$db['default']['database'] = 'db name';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: This error comes when your database details are not correct.

Comment: check for your databse name and specially for user name password for the seleted databse

Comment: my details was correct..i have uploaded this site in another host..but there i didnt find any error like this

Comment: Your databases detail might be wrong.Did user have permission to access database.Check database permission

Comment: yes user have permission to access

Comment: Ensure your username and database are strings without blank space in it eg. `db_user` and `db_name`.

Answer (score 0):

In cpannel actually username and database name has cpanel username prefix  eg

```
$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'cpanelusername_root';
$db['default']['password'] = 'password';
$db['default']['database'] = 'cpanelusername_db name';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli'; ///use this extension
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

in more simple words

```
Host = localhost (literally put localhost)
Database name = (cpanelUsername_databaseName)
Database username = (cpanelUsername_databaseUsername)
Database password = (******)
```

Answer (score 0):

write the corrects details of the username and password. Your username and password doesnot look valid at all. Space not supported
**

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'username';
$db['default']['password'] = 'password';
$db['default']['database'] = 'dbname';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';
```

this is the changes to be done in config/database.php

and also dont forget to change the base_url setting in config.php

**$config['base_url'] = 'http://yoursitename/foldername';**

**

Comment: i guess you are putting the correct details. what error do you have